# After making any 3D model using Opengl how to export it's data in .dae file?

Tags: opengl, 3d, c++, gpu, model

I'm trying to make simple 3d modeling program in c++ with Opengl. So I don't know how to transfer/convert/export or save data of 3D model  in .dae file. 
NOTE:- 3d model is made using Opengl programming.

Comment: OpenGL is just a rendering API; it doesn't know anything about saving files or file formats or COLLADA or anything of the kind. So basically, your question is that you have generated some vertex data of some kind, and you want to know how to save that in a COLLADA file. That's going to require a lot of work, involving understanding the COLLADA format, XML writing, and so forth.

Comment: Oh, that looks like my brain will require huge memory storage..hmm. Thanks for answering. 